# how to send email in background from the android phone to my email without using intent

Tags: android, email, background

how can i send  email in code  from  my phone to my account without using the intent ??
 i mean without getting the popup window that ask me witch application i want to use to send the email.

this what i used using the intent.

```
package com.example.emaildemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnSendEmail;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendEmail);        
        btnSendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {     
                String[] to = {"receiver@gmail.com"};   
                String[] cc = {"receiver.aoude@gmail.com"};           
                sendEmail(to, cc, "Hello", "Hello my friends!");
            }
        });
    }
     //---sends an SMS message to another device---
    private void sendEmail(String[] emailAddresses, String[] carbonCopies, 
    String subject, String message)
    {     
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddresses);   
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, carbonCopies);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);        
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");   
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));
    }
}
```

but what i want is that i need to send an email to my account from my phone

so if anyone can help me i will appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Check this code for [Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android). It's a step by step tutorial. Hope this works for ya!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link . I used it to send email in android from background . This link is used to send email from gmail account .

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/

Then go to your gmail account and follow the steps given below

1.Go to the "Less secure apps" section in My Account.Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)

2.Go to https://www.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN/UnlockCaptcha